# Varieties determined by a characteristic-type of polynomial with the structure of an underlying graph

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

While writing my master thesis, following problem came up:
Given a digraph $G$ with edges $e_1,..,e_n$ and a
given a $n\times n$- matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that $A_{ij}=0$ if the ending vertex of $e_j$ is not the starting vertex $e_i$, i want to look at the algebraic set $\mathcal{V}(A)$ given by the following polynomial:
$$
P_A(x_1,...,x_n)=
\det\left(\left(
    \begin{array}{c c c c} 
       x_1 &  & & \\ 
        & x_2 & & \\ 
        &  &\ddots &\\ 
        &  &  & x_n
    \end{array}\right)-A\right)
$$
First, I want to show that $P_A$ is irreducible if $A$ is irreducible and invertible, moreover I would like to know more about singularities and how one could relate properties of $G$ to properties of the (then) affine variety. I unfortunately couldn't find any literature to this, not even to varieties given by these sort of polynomials.
I'd be gratefull for any hint given!

Comment: [Crossposted at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052443/varieties-given-by-a-characteristic-type-of-polynomial).